# The Page will reload after I leave the page to other pages, then return to the page only in several seconds

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

My question is :

[image]

When I am in page 1 on the Edge, then I just click the page 2, only after several seconds(about 5~10s), when I click the page 1 again, it will reload the page.

For all the pages, they are the same.

So, if I edit some txt on the page, and go onto the other page and return the original page, it will reload the page without saving.

What can I do?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Otto